Constants under repeated inheritance in Perl: Prototype mismatch: () vs none
First excuse for this complex type of question lacking a minimal non-working example, but the code is really too complex to derive a MWE.
Anyway I'll try to explain the problem:
Starting from a working system that uses several classes with multiple and repeated inheritance in Perl (mastering that caused the complexity of the code), I wanted to change an "enum" implemented by a set of constants with an Enum type I had invented.
That Enum would generate the constants as before, but it would also remember the names as strings, so one could convert names to numbers, and the way back...
In a nutshell this code fragment in Auth::VerifyStatus.pm would create an enum (the real one is more complex):
use Enum v1.0.0;
use constant _VERIFY_STATI => Enum->new('VS_STAT', [qw(OK ERR_BAD ERR_INVALID)]);

The constants generated would be the concatenation of the base name with the list items, like VS_STAT_OK, VS_STAT_ERR_BAD, ...
That package would allow export of the constants as well as the enum, similar to this (complexity removed):
    %EXPORT_TAGS = (
        'enums' => [qw(_VERIFY_STATI)],
        'status_enum' => [_VERIFY_STATI->names()],
    );

The names method returns a list of the names (constants) generated by the Enum.
Now I have another package named Auth::Verifier.pm that does use Auth::VerifyStatus v1.7.0 qw(:status_enum); and (as it seems to be necessary) does re-export the status constants as well:
    %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'enums' => [qw(Auth::VerifyStatus::_VERIFY_STATI)],
    'status_enum' =>
        [map { 'Auth::VerifyStatus::' . $_ }
         Auth::VerifyStatus::_VERIFY_STATI->names()]);

(I added that map to qualify the package when trying to make it work, because I ran into unexpected problems)
Trying to debug the situation, I arrived nowhere; the only thing I know is that the problem starts after the final 1; in Auth::Verifier when running perl -MAuth::Verifier -de1:
...
Auth::Verifier ONE
Auth::Verifier::CODE(0x2224de0)(lib/Auth/Verifier.pm:261):
261:    1;
  DB<1> c
Constant subroutine Auth::VerifyStatus::VS_STAT_OK redefined at -e line 0.
        main::BEGIN() called at -e line 0
        eval {...} called at -e line 0
Prototype mismatch: sub Auth::VerifyStatus::VS_STAT_OK () vs none at -e line 0.
        main::BEGIN() called at -e line 0
        eval {...} called at -e line 0
...

(The "ONE" output was added immediately before the 1; at the end of the package for debugging purposes only)
The Exporter is evaluated in a BEGINblock, also as it seemed to be necessary, like this (also in the other package):
our (@EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK, %EXPORT_TAGS, @ISA, $VERSION);
BEGIN {
    use Exporter qw(import);
    $VERSION = v1.7.0;
    $DB::single = 1; # trying to debug this
    @ISA = qw(Flags);
    %EXPORT_TAGS = (
...

So I'm absolutely clueless how to debug this (too many "line 0") in a reasonable way, or how to fix this.
Or am I demanding to much from Perl and should use a real OO language instead?
Additional non-essential Details
Just for reference (as people wondered), here's how I create my constants at runtime (paranoidly structured, I'm afraid):
# query or add symbol table entry
sub _sym($;$)
{
    my ($name, $val) = @_;

    no strict 'refs';
    unless ($#_ > 0) {
        if (my ($pkg, $sym) = $name =~ /^(.*::)(.+)$/) {
            return ${$pkg}{$sym};
        }
        confess "_sym: invalid $name\n";
    }
    *{$name} = $val;
}

# query or add symbol table entry to package
sub _pkg_sym($$;$)
{
    my ($pkg, $name, $val) = @_;

    unless ($#_ > 1) {
        _sym($pkg . '::' . $name);
    } else {
        _sym($pkg . '::' . $name, $val);
    }
}

# add constant
sub _add_const($$$)
{
    my $v = $_[2];                      # constant value

    unless (_pkg_sym($_[0], $_[1])) {
        _pkg_sym($_[0], $_[1], sub () { $v });
    } else {
        carp "_add_const: $_[1] already defined in $_[0]\n";
    }
}


It's so complex you can't provide an example, but you hope we can understand it from your description and find a solution?

So as a first step maybe just ignore all the complexity and explain whether I can (or how) inherit a constant from one package to the n-the descendant, possibly even with multiple and/or repeated inheritance.

The simple answer regarding prototype mismatch is: Don't use prototypes.

Actually, he's not using prototypes directly. The simple answer is that he needs to because constant.pm already did.

Why are you trying to fix the second error before the first? Very often, earlier errors are the cause of later errors. And this appears to be the case here.

@ikegami I fully agree, but I was not able to find the "first error" at the time of asking.

I'm talking about the two errors in your question! You said you got Constant subroutine Auth::VerifyStatus::VS_STAT_OK redefined at -e line 0. before Prototype mismatch: sub Auth::VerifyStatus::VS_STAT_OK () vs none at -e line 0., but you totally ignored it!

I did not ignore it: Obviously for a prototype mismatch you need a redeclaration with a conflicting prototype; I could only suspect that my "export setup" caused it, but could not find out how. Prepending & seemed to stop those errors, so I had a starting point.

You aren't demanding too much of Perl. This is easy stuff and "real" OO has nothing to do with it. Even fake OO has nothing to do with it.
The constants module is simply a way to create subroutines that return a value that you can't change. It does some checking and creates the equivalent of:
sub SOME_CONSTANT () { 137 }

It looks like your module is somehow redefining these constant subroutines. First, you might not need to do that. If you can figure out why you are redefining things, rip that part out.
Second, if you do, give them the empty prototype so it's the same as the sub it's replacing. And maybe no warnings qw(redefine).
Basically, prototypes tell Perl how to parse the stuff around your call to a subroutine. When you change that hint in the middle of Perl parsing your program, the warning is appropriate.
We can't really see what you are doing in the way you have presented things since we don't get to see any of the mechanics though.

A "constant" is a high level idea, but we're down here in the weeds talking about how to implement it. Ultimately everything is changeable, and in Perl that's by design. In this case, SOME_CONSTANT is not an lvalue, so you can't assign to it. But, you can redefine the subroutine that provides the value.

Yes, Some other package "plants" objects into the symbol table; actually I create my package methods (getters and setters) that way (but that's a different topic).

@briandfoy Sorry, that was not really for you. It's silly that constants can be redefined, is all.

To be fair, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474349/6607497 gave the initial idea what might be wrong.
Actually at the end it turned out that there were multiple issues:

I forgot to import default-exported symbols when importing a non-default-exported symbol.
That was the reason why I needed to qualify the symbols when re-exporting them.
Also that seemed to attach a prototype different from the original prototype to the symbols exported. (I'm not quite sure about that, however)

Non-default-exporting an additional symbol, I forgot to import the non-default symbols (no import list given)


After the initial fix that brought me back on the right track, I did a different (still ugly solution).
Here is the initial fix that helped me starting:
Instead of using map { 'Auth::VerifyStatus::' . $_ } I used map { '&Auth::VerifyStatus::' . $_ } (& added in front), and perl -MAuth::Verifier -de1 proceeded to main::(-e:1):   1 without a problem.
After realizing that "exports don't inherit" (i.e. symbols exported in a base class are not automatically exported in a descendant of it) I had to re-export some symbols along the hierarchy of descendants.
When realizing that I can (ugly, ugly!) access the base packages' EXPORT variables, I added this ugly code to "inherit exports":
# ...descendant of AUTH::Verifier...
use Auth::Verifier qw(_VERIFY_STATI :status_enum);
# ...
our (@EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK, %EXPORT_TAGS, @ISA, $VERSION);
BEGIN { # the importer (i.e.: exporter) block
    my $parent1_export_tags = \%Auth::Verifier::EXPORT_TAGS;
# ...
    %EXPORT_TAGS = (
        # ...my local exports
    );
    foreach (qw(enums status_enum)) {
       $EXPORT_TAGS{$_} = $parent1_export_tags->{$_};
    }
# ...
}



The & ignores the prototype, but that's probably not what you want to do.

OK, the names are names of constants implemented as sub () { $v } (so that's where the prototype came from, I guess); how would I change it to "preserve" that prototype then?
